# Bluemix DreamFace documentation

Tags: user-interface, ibm-cloud

When I use IBM Bluemix and create a DreamFace service, I seem to find that the version of Dreamface being used is v2.5.1:

[image]

However, all the documentation points me to:

http://www.interactive-clouds.com/documentation/

Which appears to show documentation for v2.1.0:

[image]

As I watch the videos and read the web pages, I'm afraid that the differences in the versions seems to be very distinct and I am not able to comprehend as much as I would like.   Is there a newer set of documentation that matches the version of DreamFace as found in bluemix?

Comment: Hi Neil! I have contacted Interactive Clouds, who is the third-party provider of the DreamFace service, and asked them to provide an answer.

Comment: I got a direct call from a very senior individual at DreamFace who was very pleasant, apologized for my less than stellar experiences and has assured me that the mismatch between documentation and product will be addressed VERY quickly.  This has left me with a very good perception and now all that remains is for me to wait a period of time and then consume/review the new documents, videos, tutorials or other artifacts and, hopefully, be able to start evaluating DreamFace as it is hoped to be seen.